# Large standard errors in IV regression

Tags: stata, standard-error, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect

I am encountering very large standard errors of the endogenous regressor (bigger than the size of the coefficient) in the second step of my treatment-effects model (`treatreg` in Stata). When I consult Google and literature, the only reason I can find for this is that my instrument is weak. However, when I test my instrument, I get an F-value of 41.85 which as far as I can tell is pretty good. Might there be anything else going on?

Here is my ouput from running the `treatreg` command in Stata (`volunteer` = endogenous regressor, `tradition` = instrumental variable):

[image: Stata output]

Some detailed background:

I am looking at whether wages are influenced by doing volunteer work. This may be the case, in theory, since volunteering may be an investment in human and social capital which should increase earning power. However, since volunteers are often individuals with an abundance of human and social capital, bias may result from omitted variables and I therefore may have correlation with the error term.

My instrument is a self-reported dummy variable that measures whether an individual has a tradition for volunteering in their family. This variable is highly significantly correlated with whether they volunteer at present but not their wages.

Comment: That the tradition is uncorrelated with wages is based on theory or observation?

Comment: Both. 

When I correlate the two, I get r=0.0291 with p=0.2825. So there is some very week insignificant bivariate correlation.

Theoretically, I suppose that having a tradition for volunteering in the family may signal a more affluent background. But there is no correlation, and since I check for education, I don't think this should be a major issue.

Comment: What if the volunteering doesn't impact wages? I see people volunteering regardless of their income.

Comment: It might not. But then why the larger coefficient AND standard errors? Besides, the two are highly correlated with a large beta-coefficient when running regular OLS.

Comment: Could the argument not be made that `tradition` is endogenous, so that all you're doing is using a less efficient estimator whilst not taking care of the endogeneity problem?  What was the SE of `volunteer` before?

Comment: Running regular OLS, I get beta=463.27 and se=120.07 for the volunteer variable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why tradition might be endogenous? And how that might cause inflated se?

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of the linked previous question. The setting is different but the problem is the same.